# How do i embed a state map in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

```
How do i put a state map ?
```

I have a excel sheet with some city names in it with no `geo dimensions` present.

now i wanted to how do i design a Dashboard with these city names present on google map ?

Could somebody guide me in right direction !

```
region  amt profit
Annakkonamer    21  56
madurrrai   20  87
chennrrai   32  89
arrrttani   34  54
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: updated answer with data added from question (see screenshots below).

---

In `tableau` you can use the built in maps to create a dashboard, but note: this is not a google map, it is a tableau dashboard.

Here is a great tutorial on how to use the mapping function in tableau: [Mapping Basics](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/mapping-basics)

**Keep in mind**: tableau will usually do a great job of mapping your data, but if your excel is simply a list of cities without any reference to state or zip code or anything like that it might be complicated (since there are 19 Georgetowns in the USA and even 9 places called 'Palmyra').

Here is a quick example (you can see the very simple excel data I used in the small data-view window):

[image]

---

#### Just saw the update to the question.

#### This can be done, (I am using an exact copy of your data) you just need to follow these steps:

1. Connect to the data. You will see that a dimension called `region` is added. You need to convert this dimension to `Geographic` -> `City` type:
   [image]
2. Drag this dimension to the view and a map will appear. Go to Map -> Edit locations:
   [image]
3. **Very important**: make sure that the country is set to the correct one. These look like Indian cities, so I set the country to India and most were recognised:
   [image]
4. Now you can use the amt and profit measures to change the color or shape of the mapped points for the cities.
   [image]

Comment: +1.. thanks ! but in my case there are no latitudes and longitudes,there are only some names of regions !

Comment: No problem. Can you add an example of what your data looks like in the question and I'll see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: i can't put the data due to my boss issue :D... theres one column `region,amt(%),profit(%)`

Comment: How is region defined? Some mock/dummy data would help a lot.

Comment: thanks man ! i'm currenlty flying home..will accept once i get my system .